# How often can you appeal a rejection of the appeal(s) made?

Tags: corporate-law, appeal, penalty, public-transport

How often can you appeal a rejection of the appeal(s) made regarding a penalty fare notice?

The appeal is appealing to the good nature and sense of humanity and justice, as the initial appeal was rejected. There was no specific reason how and why they came to conclude with a rejection. It simply claimed that the experience and explanation of the passenger was not "justified". My appeal had no intention to justify anything, I was merely explaining what I had experienced. Or are these the public transportation companies using the term "justification' interchangeably with "satisfaction"?

Comment: So just to clarify- your appeal was based on nothing but "pretty please?"

Comment: What decision was appealed? where? What is a "*penalty fare notice*"? You need to add relevant details because your post is very unclear. Also, although I usually disagree with mutilating others' posts, I must point out that the latter part of [yours](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/89405/1) seems unrelated to the rest of your post. Even labeling it as "rhetorical question" is inaccurate.

Comment: This site is for law questions, not rantimg about your employer.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Penalty Fare Notice: the "you didn't have a valid ticket to take the bus, now pay us increased-fare instead"

Comment: Also: Please clarify which institution and where,

Answer (score 6):

You didn't bother to state who this appeal is with or even where you are but I'm almost certain I know the answer.

Just once.

If the appeal is denied, you may be able to appeal to a higher body such as a higher court or an ombudsman. However, any group or court allowing the same appeal ad infinitum until you get what you want would be farcical.

Comment: Endless appeals are usually applied on different technical grounds, each with their own justification. You then *appeal the appeals* on those same (or different) technical grounds. It's the way in which death-row inmates are kept alive for decades or asylum seekers avoid deportation with the support of friendly lawyers.